# JavaScript: calling a function by name on hashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

I'm trying to call a function given the function name in the hash string. I have the following code:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  //alert(location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length));
  window[location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length)];
});

function test() {
  alert('123!');
}
```

The funny thing is, when I uncomment the `alert` call, everything works as expected. When the `alert` is commented, however, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you calling a function ?

Comment: Sounds like what you are trying to do will open a [major XSS hole](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Comment: @Bergi: I'm only using this for page navigation within a mobile web app. The functions that are called serve the purpose of rendering the page via API calls, which requires authentication, so I don't think it really opens up a security risk (but correct me if I'm wrong). Thanks!

Comment: Do these API calls change something or are they only GET requests? Authentication might have happened before, so the user does not notice what happens. Also, this code allows execution of arbitrary (and possibly unwanted) functions, try to open `www.yourpage.com/#alert`. So put these function on their own object, not the global window object, and you can control which (callable) properties it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window[location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length)];
```

doesn't call a function.

If you want to call the function whose name is `location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length)`, you may do

```
window[location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length)]();
```

**Side note :**

```
location.hash.substring(1, location.hash.length)
```

can be shortened in

```
location.hash.slice(1)
```

Comment: Yep, forgot the parentheses. Thanks!